# How to track Omniture Custom Traffic Variable in Android?

Tags: android, analytics, adobe-analytics, traffic-measurement

In Site Catalyst we have defined Custom Traffic Variable "Item Bought". Now how do i send request to update this custom variable from Android library? i don't find much help [here](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/android/index.html#AppMeasurement_for_Android_3x)

Please find my code below,

```
    public class TrackingHelper {
    private static final String TRACKING_RSID = "MY_TRACKING_RSID";
    private static final String TRACKING_SERVER = "MY_TRACKING_SERVER";
    static ADMS_Measurement measurement = null;

    public static void startActivity(Activity activity) {
        measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance(activity);
        measurement.startActivity(activity);
    }

    public static void stopActivity() {
        measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance();
        measurement.stopActivity();
    }

    public static void configureAppMeasurement(Activity activity) {
        if (measurement == null) {
            measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance(activity);
            measurement.configureMeasurement(TRACKING_RSID, TRACKING_SERVER);
            measurement.setOfflineTrackingEnabled(true);
            measurement.setDebugLogging(true);
        }
    }

    public static void trackItemBought() {
        if (measurement != null) {
            measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance();
            Hashtable<String, Object> contextData = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
            contextData.put("Item Bought", "Item Bought");
            measurement.setEvents("Item Bought");
            measurement.track(contextData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for the android code, but here are some general thoughts:

When you send a context data variable, you send a name-value pair, so I suspect this line:
contextData.put("Item Bought", "Item Bought");
Should be something more like this (I'm going to say the item being bought is a basketball):
contextData.put("Item Bought", "Basketball");

Then someone with access to processing rules in SiteCatalyst will need to configure a rule to say that that variable ("Item Bought") belongs to its assigned custom traffic variable (prop14, for instance). http://www.jasonegan.net/2011/04/07/omniture-sitecatalyst-15-context-variables-processing-rules/ talks about how to do that a bit, but the article generally assumes you have a certain level of knowledge of SiteCatalyst.

Comment: But i want the Item Bought to be incremental as i am suppose to buy only one Item.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the following change in your code.

```
public class TrackingHelper {
private static final String TRACKING_RSID = "MY_TRACKING_RSID";
private static final String TRACKING_SERVER = "MY_TRACKING_SERVER";
static ADMS_Measurement measurement = null;

public static void startActivity(Activity activity) {
    measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance(activity);
    measurement.startActivity(activity);
}

public static void stopActivity() {
    measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance();
    measurement.stopActivity();
}

public static void configureAppMeasurement(Activity activity) {
    if (measurement == null) {
        measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance(activity);
        measurement.configureMeasurement(TRACKING_RSID, TRACKING_SERVER);
        measurement.setOfflineTrackingEnabled(true);
        measurement.setDebugLogging(true);
    }
}

public static void trackItemBought() {
    if (measurement != null) {
        measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance();
        Hashtable<String, Object> contextData = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        contextData.put("Item Bought", "Item Bought");
        measurement.setEvents("Item Bought");
        measurement.contextData(contextData);
        measurement.track();
    }
}
```